# Show default value if not value match in database for TextBox AutoComplete using Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I am running one windows application, Where i need to use one autocomplete textbox. Here i am able to display text which user search with their letter matching with database tables and populate in autocomplete. Now the requirement here is if no value match with database then it should display No record found in autocomplete list. And once user click on it should open the new form.

What i have tried so far is below:

For Textbox control i set the properties : AutoCompleteMode = Suggest and AutoCompleteSource = CustomSource.

Now in Form_Load Event i used below code:

```
var clientList = GetClientListByName(string.Empty);
        AutoCompleteStringCollection asc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        foreach (Customers c in clientList)
        {
            asc.Add(c.MessersName);
            asc.Add(c.FirstName);
            asc.Add(c.Phone);
            txtClientName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = asc;
        }

 private List<Customers> GetClientListByName(string clientName)
    {
        List<Customers> lstCustomers = new List<Customers>();
        DataTable dtUser = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SearchClient", conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                {
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchData", clientName));
                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Type", "S"));
                    sa.Fill(dtUser);
                    lstCustomers = BindGrid(dtUser, clientName);
                }
            }
        }
        return lstCustomers;
    }
```

Below is the procedure Script used for it.

```
declare @Len int
select @Len = Len(@SearchData)
IF(@Type='S')
BEGIN
    IF(@LEN > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SCOMPANY WHERE [CompanyName] like '%'+@SearchData+'%' )
        BEGIN
            Select CompId, CompanyName from SCOMPANY where [CompanyName] like '%'+@SearchData+'%'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1 as CompId, 'No record found, Click to add new' as CompanyName
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Select CompId, CompanyName from SCOMPANY
    END
END
```

Now the issue, What i am facing here is when i type the character matching with database table, I am getting the matching record in autocomplete list, But when i type the character is not matching to the data then I am not getting the text Record not found from stored procedure.

I tried the Form_Load event code inside TextBox textchanged event but there also when debug i am getting the text record not found but it is not populating in the autocomplete.

Need help.

Comment: There are many problems here. To start you always pass a _string.Empty_ to the stored procedure but a search for _%%_ returns true so you always return all the companies, but the string 'No record found....' is never returned and AutoComplete cannot find it if you start typing the letter N.

Comment: @Steve: If you look the procedure body where if string len > 0 then it will check the text in the table. but if the data not found it will go to the else part where i am returning the No record found. I debug the code in application code behind and found like it returns the value record not found and set in the AutoCompleteStringCollection but that value never populate in the textbox. I comment the else part in procedure to take compid and compname if text length is 0.

Comment: Now when i type N then i could see it shows No Record found but i need here to show this text if non of the item match in the table.